# findViewById во фрагменте

Tags: android, kotlin

При использовании в классе фрагмента выводит ошибку `Unresolved reference: findViewById`.
Как реализовать `findViewById` во фрагменте или возможно использовать что-то другое?

Кнопка на которую я ссылаюсь находится в одноименном фрагменте активити:

```
package com.example.myapplication.ui.gallery

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.example.myapplication.R
import com.example.myapplication.ScrollingActivity

class GalleryFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var galleryViewModel: GalleryViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?

    ): View? {
        galleryViewModel =
                ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false)
        galleryViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        })
        return root
        var podborbtn = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.podborbtn)
        podborbtn.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(context, ScrollingActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Метод findViewById() работает только для активити. Чтобы обратиться к виджетам в фрагменте, вам нужно искать их в View, которую вы инфлейтили для разметки фрагмента. При этом локальную переменную root нужно вынести в поле класса, чтобы иметь к ней доступ вне ее метода, либо искать виджеты в этом методе и уже их делать полем класса для доступа по всему фрагменту. В вашем случае: root.findViewById().

Comment: @pavlofff возможно имеет смысл оформить ответом